# No date-time format found matching timeStamp jmeter report aggregator

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, locust, taurus

I used to create aggregate report from Jmeter jtl file with the following command:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=false -jar cmdrunner-2.2.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv locust.csv --input-jtl 'kpi.jtl' --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

And it works fine with the following kpi.jtl file

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Hostname,Connect
1589039402858,2795,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-1,true,53150,8,8,0,macbook718,0
1589039403878,2256,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-2,true,53091,11,11,0,macbook718,0
1589039403901,2243,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-3,true,52959,11,11,0,macbook718,0
1589039403923,2226,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-4,true,53092,11,11,0,macbook718,0
1589039404954,2230,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-5,true,53211,15,15,0,macbook718,0
1589039404970,2220,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-6,true,53142,15,15,0,macbook718,0
1589039404986,2233,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-7,true,52923,15,15,0,macbook718,0
1589039405004,2259,jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 11, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-8,true,53176,15,15,0,macbook718,0
1589039406157,1645,jmeter_view_issue,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 9, number of failing samples : 0",Jira 1-2,true,40847,15,15,0,macbook718,0
```

But with almost the same jtl content:

```
timeStamp,label,elapsed,bytes,responseCode,responseMessage,success,allThreads,Latency
1589039402858,locust_login_and_view_dashboard,2219,0,200,OK,true,3,0
1589039403878,locust_login_and_view_dashboard,2418,0,200,OK,true,4,0
1589039403901,locust_login_and_view_dashboard,2103,0,200,OK,true,5,0
```

I have Jmeter Reporter error:

```
2020-05-10 17:34:54,704 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: timeStamp did not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, trying next date format
2020-05-10 17:34:54,704 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: timeStamp did not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2020-05-10 17:34:54,705 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: timeStamp did not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, trying next date format
2020-05-10 17:34:54,705 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: timeStamp did not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2020-05-10 17:34:54,705 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: timeStamp did not match MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2020-05-10 17:34:54,705 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 1. java.text.ParseException: No date-time format found matching timeStamp
2020-05-10 17:34:54,705 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: kpi.jtl
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: java.text.ParseException: No date-time format found matching timeStamp
```

Seems like all headers in the second JTL file are correct. And the same timestamp. 
Why do I have this exhausting error? Maybe I missed some required headers in jtl file?


UPD. I figured out that problem was in ORDER of headers. 
Do you know some command line keys to skip checking ORDER in Aggregator Report?

Now issue is:

```
2020-05-10 18:26:09,745 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'sampleresult.default.encoding', defaulting to: ISO-8859-1
2020-05-10 18:26:09,757 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'jmeterPlugin.prefixPlugins'
2020-05-10 18:26:09,758 INFO k.a.j.PluginsCMDWorker: Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A
2020-05-10 18:26:09,761 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_UA
2020-05-10 18:26:09,766 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading user properties from: /Users/smoro/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.2.1/bin/user.properties
2020-05-10 18:26:09,766 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading system properties from: /Users/smoro/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.2.1/bin/system.properties
2020-05-10 18:26:10,606 WARN o.a.j.g.ObjectTableModel: Header count=13 but classes count=11
2020-05-10 18:26:10,606 WARN o.a.j.g.ObjectTableModel: Header count=13 but writeFunctor count=11
2020-05-10 18:26:10,755 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2020-05-10 18:26:10,766 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2020-05-10 18:26:10,769 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2020-05-10 18:26:10,777 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2020-05-10 18:26:10,777 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2020-05-10 18:26:10,777 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2020-05-10 18:26:10,777 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2020-05-10 18:26:10,778 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Insufficient columns to parse field 'Latency' at line 2
```

Comment: It not the problem with order of the headers. While generating the jtl files, you may select CSV/XML type content in the configuration of the Jmeter. You Can also Verify first Jtl consists more columns compare to second jtl.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) the order of the column in the [jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) is fixed, you can only add/remove specific metrics using [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

So there is nothing you can do from JMeter side unless you want to patch [CSVSaveService](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/save/CSVSaveService.java) and amend the order of columns there.

If you're trying to generate a HTML Reporting Dashboard from [Locust](https://locust.io/) test results it might be easier to go using Grafana, see [Locust Monitoring with Grafana](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-monitoring-with-grafana-in-just-fifteen-minutes) in Just 15 Minutes for comprehensive instructions